# Spark and MSSQL insert speed

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I've encountered an issue where it takes spark about one hour to insert hundreds of thousands records into MSSQL database using JDBC driver.

- Spark version: 2.2.0
- MSSQL JDBC Driver version: 6.1.0.jre8

Looking at profile I noticed that Spark (or most likely JDBC driver) is generating a separate insert for each row in my DataFrame and that's of course is slow.

I looked at JDBC configuration and did not find a way to enable batched inserts.

Is there a way to config Spark application so that it inserts data using BULK INSERT or generates big batches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft released special [Spark connector for Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector#official-supported-versions) to provide this functionality that also works for normal MsSql database. You can see bulk insert example on their GitHub page https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark#bulk-copy-to-azure-sql-database-or-sql-server